# MediaPlayer.setDataSource(); java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-download-manager

I'm downloading an MP3 with `DownloadManager` and when download finished i try to playing the MP3 with `MediaPlayer`.

after download finished, when i get the `length()` of file return ZERO that causes i get java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed error from `MediaPlayer.setDataSource()`. if i wait a few seconds and then setting data source for MediaPlayer, works fine!

```
public void initMediaPlayer() {
        if (mediaPlayer == null)
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);

        try {
            File audioDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(AUDIO_SERVICE), activeAudio.getAudioBooksTableOfContentsID() + ".mp3");
            if (audioDir.exists()) {
                FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(audioDir);
                Log.d("audioDir.length()", String.valueOf(audioDir.length()));

                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(is.getFD()); //audioDir.getPath()

                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1153)
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1136)
W/System.err:     at com.example.services.MediaPlayerService.initMediaPlayer(MediaPlayerService.java:280)
W/System.err:     at com.example.services.MediaPlayerService.playNewAudio(MediaPlayerService.java:757)
W/System.err:     at com.example.services.MediaPlayerService.handleIncomingActions(MediaPlayerService.java:718)
at com.example.services.MediaPlayerService.onStartCommand(MediaPlayerService.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3327)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1583)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: try to give file path like this      player.setDataSource("file://mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp.apptalk/AudioRecorder/22-Oct-2015 11:26:14.mp4");

Comment: @Anonymous I tried it, but it did not make any difference

Comment: still your are getting same error?

Comment: post your manifest

Answer (score 1):

`setDataSource` error usually that the file doesn't exists. it also might be that your webpack ( etc .. ) didn't copied it to its target or the path you're using isn't correct.

But I would start from finding in the package what was copied and make sure the file is there before trying to guess the file path to write.